# Restangular Get() and Post() work with additional POST error "..../adsf 405 method not allow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources, asp.net-web-api2, restangular

I have sample Web API 2 with following methods using Route.
from Restangular I retrieve with .get('x'), then I get one object, after pass through promise's success function, I get additional POST error saying 
    `http://xxxx/api/Folder/**XX**/adsf **404 (Not Found)**,`
where XX means any Id value from that retrieved object.

Web API C#

```
[Route("Api/Folder")] 
public IEnumerable<Models.mockup.FolderModel> GetRoots()
    {
        return Models.mockup.FolderModel.Mock();
    }
    [Route("Api/Folder/{objId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string objId)
    {
        Models.mockup.FolderModel _f = Models.mockup.FolderModel.Mock().ToArray()[3];
        return Ok(_f);
    }
    [Route("Api/Folder")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Models.mockup.FolderModel value)
    {
        string s = "testing";
        value.Name = "server respnse";
        return Ok(new Models.mockup.FolderModel());
    }
```

and following is Restangular in AngularJs

```
        Restangular.all('api/Folder').get('whatever').then(function(data){
            var _a = data;
         })
```

I get the data i requested for from get, but additionally, there is a POST error as below too. where is that **adsf** comes from? and why my get request is sending post too?

Error in Chrome Console : 
     `**POST http://xxxx:51997/api/Folder/3/adsf 404 (Not Found) **`
where 3 is the ID from retrieved object

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found out the reason why it's happening. It's my mistake, I place data.post('adsf') in Chrome's watch expression to debug something long time back. And it was posting it and causing this issue.

It's good to cleanup these Debug Watch Expressions from time to time.